# Reading 2 fgets inputs to use strncpy for first and last name

Tags: c, input, fgets, strncpy

Need to put first and last name together. Must use fgets and recommended to use strncpy to prevent overflow. After code compiles, only allows input for last name. Any thoughts?

```
char fname[10];
char lname[10];
char fullname[20];

printf("Enter first name:  ");
fgets(fname, 10, stdin);

printf("Enter your last name: ");
fgets(lname, 10, stdin);

strncpy(fullname, fname, 20);
strncpy(fullname, lname, 20);

printf("Welcome, %s\n", fullname);
return;
```

Current Results:

Enter first name: Enter your last name: abcd
Welcome, abcd

Not able to enter both names

Comment: perhaps change the second `strncpy` to `strncat`

Comment: Note also that fgets will usually leave a trailing new line at the end of the string.  You'll probably want to replace that with a space.

Comment: Ramone_McKnuckles, Who suggested `strncpy()` versus `strcpy()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>

     /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ** Allow user to enter a string with optional prompt.
     **
     ** Parameters:
     **    _O_input       String input by the user.
     **    I__inputSize   Size of the _O_input string.
     **    I__prompt      User prompt string, or NULL.
     */
     int InputString(
           char *_O_input,
           size_t I__inputSize,
           const char *I__prompt
        )
        {
        int rCode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
        char *cp;

        /* Display input prompt, if specified. */
        if(I__prompt)
           printf("%s", I__prompt);

        /* Call fgets(), and check for failure. */
        if(!fgets(_O_input, I__inputSize, stdin))
           {
           rCode=EXIT_FAILURE;
           fprintf(stderr, "ERR: fgets() failed.\n");
           goto CLEANUP;
           }

        /* Remove the trailing newline from the _O_input string. */
        cp=strchr(_O_input, '\n');
        if(cp)
           *cp='\0';

     CLEANUP:

        return(rCode);
        }

     /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ** Program start.
     */
     int main(void)
        {
        int rCode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
        char fname[9+1];  /*Nine charactears plus the string termination character.*/
        char lname[9+1];
        char fullname[19+1];

        /* Have user input first name. */
        rCode=InputString(fname, sizeof(fname), "Enter first name:  ");
        if(rCode)
           {
           fprintf(stderr, "ERR: InputString() reports: %d\n", rCode);
           goto CLEANUP;
           }

        /* Have user input last name. */
        rCode=InputString(lname, sizeof(lname), "Enter last name:  ");
        if(rCode)
           {
           fprintf(stderr, "ERR: InputString() reports: %d\n", rCode);
           goto CLEANUP;
           }

        /* Safely combine first and last names into fullname */
        snprintf(fullname, sizeof(fullname), "%s %s", fname, lname);

        /* Display welcome message. */
        printf("Welcome, %s\n", fullname);

     CLEANUP:

        return(rCode);
        }
```